# Borrow a struct field mutably and pass it to mutable methods

Tags: rust

Because rust doesn't track individual field borrows across method calls - it assumes you've borrowed from the whole struct, it's not possible to borrow a field from the struct, return it, and then pass that into other mutable methods. That sounds contrived but I have this exact issue right now.

```
    struct Foo {
        x: i32,
        y: i32
    }
    
    impl Foo {
        pub fn borrow_x(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {
            &mut self.x
        }
    
        pub fn cross_product(&mut self, other: &mut i32) {
            self.y *= *other;
            *other *= self.y;
        }
    }
    
    fn main() {
        let mut foo = Foo{x: 2, y: 4};
        let x_ref = foo.borrow_x();
        foo.cross_product(x_ref);
    
        println!("x={} y={}", foo.x, foo.y);
    }
```

This of course isn't permitted in rust, the error from the compiler is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `foo` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
19 |     let x_ref = foo.borrow_x();
   |                 --- first mutable borrow occurs here
20 |     foo.cross_product(x_ref);
   |     ^^^               ----- first borrow later used here
   |     |
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
```

My first reaction is to use unsafe to tell the compiler that it doesn't really borrow from self:

```
    pub fn borrow_x<'a>(&mut self) -> &'a mut i32 {
        unsafe {
            std::mem::transmute::<&mut i32, &'a mut i32>(&mut self.x)
        }
    }
```

It works, but it requires that you don't actually break rust's aliasing rules and reference foo.x elsewhere by accident.

Then I thought maybe I could split the struct so that the borrow and cross_product methods are on different sibling structs. This does work:

```
struct Bar {
    x: X,
    y: Y,
}

struct X {
    inner: i32
}

impl X {
    pub fn borrow_x(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {
        &mut self.inner
    }
}

struct Y {
    inner: i32
}

impl Y {
    pub fn cross_product(&mut self, other: &mut i32) {
        self.inner *= *other;
        *other *= self.inner;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar{x: X{inner: 2}, y: Y{inner: 4}};
    let x_ref = bar.x.borrow_x();
    bar.y.cross_product(x_ref);

    println!("x={} y={}", bar.x.inner, bar.y.inner);
}
```

I think one could ditch the method all-together and pass references to both fields into cross_product as a free function. That should be equivalent to the last solution. I find that kind of ugly though, especially as the number of fields needed from the struct grow.

Are there other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind is that rust is working at a per-function level.

```
        pub fn cross_product(&mut self, other: &mut i32) {
            self.y *= *other;
            *other *= self.y;
        }
```

The mutability rules ensure that `self.y` and `other` are not the same thing.
If you're not careful you can run into this kind of bug in C++/C/Java quite easily.

i.e. imagine if instead of

```
        let x_ref = foo.borrow_x();
        foo.cross_product(x_ref);
```

you were doing

```
        let y_ref = foo.borrow_y();
        foo.cross_product(y_ref);
```

What value should `foo.y` end up with? (Allowing these to refer to the same object can cause certain performance optimisations to not be applicable too)

As you mentioned, you could go with a free function

```
fn cross_product(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
  a *= b;
  b *= a;
}
```

but I'd consider ditching mutability altogether

```
fn cross_product(a:i32, b:i32) -> (i32,i32) {
  (a*b, a*b*b)
}
```

*ASIDE: If the return value seems odd to you (it did to me initially too) and you expected `(a*b, a*b)` you need to think a little harder... and I'd say that alone is a good reason to avoid the mutable version.*

Then I can use it like this

```
let (_x,_y) = cross_product(foo.x, foo.y);
foo.x = _x; 
foo.y = _y;
```

This is a bit verbose, but when [RFC-2909](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2909-destructuring-assignment.md) lands we can instead write:

```
(foo.y, foo.x) = cross_product(foo.x, foo.y);
```